# Display in a table a Metric column, and then a Dimension column, and then a Metric column again

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way to display in a standard table, first the NameTickets and then the Name ?
Or even better, display in the table Name and NameTickets, then City and CityTickets.

link to the report-
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/01cc1c59-4169-4c1e-aa41-9fd92b67501c

link to the sourse-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OCK00HKin432KdkQ5AmcqiB-OpI8hCFhkegA6d-jf1o/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dimension section both dimension and metric entries are allowed. However, no aggregation of metric values is possible. Thus no calculated sum or count can be used here.

Since you know the dimension fields in your table, you can create a blend data with only these dimension fields and add all other needed columns to the metric part and add here the needed aggregation. Using that blend dataset, the (already aggregated) metrics and dimension can be put together in the dimension part.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show it on the report I shared?

Comment: To add a color scale, the value is additional needed in the metric part. Here it can be hidden by formating the column with background.